# How to correctly configure report for average session duration and other time related metrics in google spreadsheets (using the GA-addon)?

Tags: google-analytics, google-sheets

I am trying to create a table in Google Spreadsheets, displaying average session duration for different URLs (see picture).
[image]

When I run the report, I get huge numbers that I can't work with.
For example:

67.938.354.766.278.800

Does anyone know how to convert these numbers into the same format Google Analytics uses? (hh:mm:ss)

Answer (score 0):

You get both sessionDuration and avgSessionDuration metrics in second ([reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=session&jump=ga_sessionduration)). This is the reason why you get huge numbers for total duration.

In Google Sheets you can find duration formatting under Format -> Number -> Duration. However, to be able to use this formatting, you should convert seconds to days. I think for this use case, division by 86400 could be used, as leap seconds are not likely to alter your results.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm afraid I have already tried that but the numbers are so rediculously big that Google Sheets doesn't even convert them to the Duration Format.

Comment: Oh I feel kinda stupid now. I just needed to divide the total Session Duration by the amount of Sessions manually.... Problem solved! Thanks for the reminder to check the Dimensions and Metrics page!